# Facebook Connect - Logging out

Tags: cakephp, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I using facebook connect in my application. i am not able to logout of the account.

logout

```
    $this->Session->destroy();
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
```

now i logout of Facebook.com and in my application i click Facebook Connect. it still logs me in with out asking me to login to facebook.com.

Wierd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting the Cookie => true so FB Connect could recognize me even if i was logged out.